# Ubuntu: reinstalling jpeg library

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python

I do not know alot about linux so please take a bit longer time trying to figure out what i am asking for.

background story can be read here : http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/5cd35edc04876523

But here is short recap:
I installed stackless python and found that i have to compile myself several python libraries to get my django project up and running again. I compiled setuptools & python-mysqldb, I downloaded and compiled jpeg, freetype2 and PIL.

Right now the problem is that django fails to validate imagefile when i upload file with a modelform. Do not turn this question down if you know nothing about django or python. this question is not neccessarily all about that.

When tracking down the point in django code which raises the error i found that it was done at the point where python used Image.load() function on uploaded image. When i commented that line out i recieved this error:

```
IOError at /profile/edit/

decoder jpeg not available

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    127.0.0.1/profile/edit/
Exception Type:     IOError
Exception Value:    decoder jpeg not available
Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in _getdecoder, line 375
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.2
Python Path:    ['/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-linux-i686.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL', '/home/projects', '/home/projects/tst']
```

As i understand it fails to do something with jpeg. Could that mean that even though i have compiled and installed this jpeg library ( jpegsrc.v7.tar.gz from ww.ijg.org), there is still something wrong with paths or something else.

I did try doing sudo make uninstall in the folder where i had compiled jpeg and it removed the files that I had installed. But ubuntu installation also had this library installed before i ever did anything with stackless.

So after all this long story the question is:
How can i get rid of Jpeg from my computer so i can make sure that jpeg decoder used everywhere is the jpeg decoder that i have compiled and installed?

Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the package python-imaging seems to have solved this issue on multiple distros.

--
cheers,
Peter

Comment: You mean, purging and installing Python-imaging package again after i have compiled stackless python. does'nt that cause another set of problems as the pre made package is meant to work with original python 2.6?